# Spring kafka not able to read truststore file from classpath

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am building an kafka consumer app which needs SASL_SSL config. Some how apache kafka is not recognizing truststore file located in classpath and looks like there is an open request to enhance it in kafka(KAFKA-7685).

In the mean time what would be the best way to solve this problem. Same app needs to deployed in PCF too so solution should work both during local windows based development and PCF (linux).

Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Here is the code which does file copy to java temp dir

```
String tempDirPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    System.out.println("Temp dir : " + tempDirPath);
    File truststoreConf = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Truststore.jks");
    File truststoreFile = new File(tempDirPath + truststoreConf.getName());
    FileUtils.copyFile(truststoreConf, truststoreFile);
    System.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", truststoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ClassPathResource` and `FileCopyUtils` to copy it from the jar to a file in a temporary directory in `main()` before creating the `SpringApplication`.

Comment: Somehow after copying file to java temp dir and using it as ssl.truststore.location giving me an error like this
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658) ~[na:1.8.0_151]

Comment: Same file if i give absolute path from src/main/resources then it works fine. Something I am missing which i cannot understand.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are copying the file.

Comment: Added code snippets which copies files from classpath to java tmp dir

Comment: try `FileCopyUtils.copy(new ClasspathResource(...).getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(...));`.

Comment: It is copying the file correctly in java temp dir thru code but somehow it is not able to load and giving the error org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore C:\Users\Pritesh\AppData\Local\Temp\Truststore.jks of type JKS

Comment: I suggest running in a debugger to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of this issue was resource filtering enabled. Maven during resource filtering corrupts the binary file. So if you have that enabled, disable it